# Backup specific SVN Revision

Tags: svn, backup, tortoisesvn, revision-history, svn-repository

I have repository which contains multiple projects in the trunk folder. 
The requirement is to keep the latest 3 revisions in the repository of each projects and backup the remaining revisions. 
Example: "test1" application has revisions 1-10.
I need to keep the revisions 10,9, and 8 (latest revisions) and backup the remaining revisions.(1-7).

"test2" application has revisions 11-16.
I need to keep the revisions 16,15, and 14 (latest revisions) and backup the remaining revisions.(11-13).
And so on...

As I am new to SVN, I'm quite unsure on how it could be done.
Can someone please help on how it can be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole point of version control tools is to keep change history. Are you trying to solve some specific problem or it's just management getting on the way of stuff they can't understand?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delayed reply. The issue is due to the "SVN running out of space". So the management asked to keep the 1st 3 versions and move the subsequent versions to a different network drive. Can this be done?

Comment: There's an experiment you could do: dump the three latest revisions with `svnadmin dump`, rename the repository folder, import the dump in a new folder with the same name and see how Subversion clients react. Needless to say, that will render version control pretty much useless for daily work, hardly any better that using DropBox.